# escaping single quotes in a mysql REGEXP query

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I tried to use a regular expression in mysql, and it works well except when I use quotes in my word.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP "^pagina's[^[:space:]]*$"
```

i tried all the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP "^'.preg_quote("pagina's").'[^[:space:]]*$"
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP "^'.addslashes("pagina's").'[^[:space:]]*$"
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP "^'.mysql_escape_real_string("pagina's").'[^[:space:]]*$"
```

no luck..

it won't give me any results because of the single quote (') in the word "pagina's".

How can I escape all quotes so mysql will see the quote literal and match a field in the database?

** EDIT **

this is my PHP code:

```
$word = "pagina's";
$ary[] = "LOWER(idx.sidx_word) REGEXP '^".preg_quote($word)."[^[:space:]]*$'";
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you use `preq_quote("pagina's")`?

Comment: yes i tried all the following:

SELECT * WHERE REGEXP "^'.preg_quote("pagina's").'[^[:space:]]*$"

and

SELECT * WHERE REGEXP "^'.addslashes("pagina's").'[^[:space:]]*$"

and

SELECT * WHERE REGEXP "^'.mysql_escape_real_string("pagina's").'[^[:space:]]*$"

no luck..

Comment: NEVER use [addslashes](http://php.net/addslashes) to escape data passed to a MySQL query. Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) if you need to escape something.

Comment: Can you post that in the question area?

Comment: what is your current PHP code?

Comment: @SirCumz: click "edit" to add information to your original question. It is unreadable and inconvenient to use comments give important information like code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a table and a column name... and you are not properly escaping the quote.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column REGEXP '^pagina''s[^[:space:]]*$';
```

Comment: i know but i only care about the REGEX part

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Have you successfully run the query directly in the mysql console?  Did you get results then?  You might get better answers if you post the actual query you are running and maybe some sample data.

Comment: i updated my post with the PHP code.

the query runs oke with all other strings i use except for the words which contains single quotes.

Comment: But have you tried your query without PHP using a string with a single quote?  Have you been able to make that work?

Comment: I'm surprised that mysql_escape_real_string() didn't work.  This leads me to believe that your regex is not producing the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a column name for the regexp and scape the quote with slash:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column REGEXP '^pagina\'s[^[:space:]]*$';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternate between enclosing single/double quotes to match double/single quotes. For matching any character, enclose the character(s) to match in "[]". When special characters (eg. "[","]", "\"), prefix with a backslash inside the "[]" brackes.

To solve the problem of having both single and double quotes in the REGEXP match,or matching any character,  construct the regular expression using CONCAT() and CHAR() if needed. See my examples below:

```
/* create test string (\377 is octal): abc'\377"de\\f[x]  */
SET @tststr := CONCAT("abc'",char(255),'"de\\f[x]' ); 
SELECT @tststr;  /*show the test string */

SELECT @tststr REGEXP "'" ; /* match single quote */
SELECT @tststr REGEXP '"' ; /* match double quote */
SELECT @tststr REGEXP char(255) ; /* match \xfe char */
SELECT @tststr REGEXP '\\' ; /*  FAIL: match backslash: this one fails  */
SELECT @tststr REGEXP '[\\]' ; /* OK: match backslash */

SELECT @tststr REGEXP 'f[\[]x[\]]$' ; /* OK: match ending sequence */ 
SELECT @tststr REGEXP 'f[[]x[]]$' ;   /* OK: oddly, this works too (unbalanced brackets)  */ 

/* Match entire sequence. Some characters may not need "[]" enclosing.
 * CONCAT() may be needed to construct the complex regular expressions. 
 */ 
SELECT @tststr REGEXP CONCAT("^abc'",char(255),'"de[\\]f[[]x[]]$' ) ; 
SELECT @tststr REGEXP CONCAT("^abc'[",char(255),']"de[\\]f[[]x[]]$' ) ; /* OK: This works too */
```